# Longest substring of correct parenthesis

Tags: c, algorithm, stack

I'm running into a bit of a problem. I have to compute the longest substring of correctly closed parenthesis and so far I've managed to do this:

```
while (work_stack.size != 0){
    //I have a working stack in which I have stored the elements
    //which in my case are brackets and while I have elements
    //i pop the first element and see if it's a left or right
    a1 = pop(&work_stack.data);
    work_stack.size--;

    if ('{' == ((Pair*)a1->info)->type ||
        '(' == ((Pair*)a1->info)->type ||
        '[' == ((Pair*)a1->info)->type)  {
        //if it's a left bracket, then I add it to the left stack
        //which i'm going to use to compare with the right sided
        //brackets i will encounter.
            stanga++; //i'm incrementing the no of left brackets
        if(ok == 0) //if there wasn't a match, then length is set to 0
            length = 0;
        if (ok == 1 && stanga > 1)
            //if there was a match but then two brackets of left side
            //are encountered, then length = 0
            /*
            Now I figured that here I am wrong. Given the input:
            [][()()])())[][)]
            The right value should be 8, but my code encounters
            two left values and sets the length to 0. I need to 
            find a way to determine if the substring is worth keeping
            */
            length = 0;
        push(&left.data, a1);
        left.size++;
    }
    if ('}' == ((Pair*)a1->info)->type ||
        ')' == ((Pair*)a1->info)->type ||
        ']' == ((Pair*)a1->info)->type){
        //if it's a right bracket and there are elements in the left
        //then i pop the first element fro the left stack and compare
        //it to my current bracket
        if(left.size != 0){
            stanga = 0;
            a2 = pop(&left.data);
            left.size--;

            //opposing is a function that returns 1 if 
            //i encounter something like ( ) or [ ] or { }
            //if the brackets are opposed, i increment the length
            if (oposing(((Pair*)a2->info)->type, ((Pair*)a1->info)->type) == 1){
                length += 2;
                ok = 1;
            }

            //otherwise, it seems that I have run into a stopping 
            //point, so I'm emptying the left stack because those 
            //paranthesis are not of use anymore and I'm saving
            //the maximum length acquired by now
            if (oposing(((Pair*)a2->info)->type, ((Pair*)a1->info)->type) == 0){
                ok = 0;
                while(left.size > 0){
                    a2 = pop(&left.data);
                    left.size--;    
                }
                if(length > max){
                    max = length;
                    length = 0;
                }
            }
            //if i haven't encountered a stopping point, i just 
            //compare the length to my max and save it if it's bigger   
            if (length > max)
                max = length;
        }
        //this line says that if the size of the left stack is 0 and
        //i have encountered a right bracket, then I can't form a 
        //correct substring, so the length is 0
        else length = 0;
    }
}
```

To note that: `((Pair*)a1->info)->type` is my character. 
Thank you!
Later Edit:
- I'm adding the structures for stack and Pair

```
typedef struct{
   int id;
   char type;
}Pair;

typedef struct cel{
   void *info;
   struct cel *urm;
}Celula, *TLista, **ALista;

typedef struct{
   TLista data;
   int size;
}stack;
```

My stack has the data type as a linked list but that shouldn't matter that much as the operations are correct (push and pop).

Edit: Added some new improvements to the code, as well as a new expalanation in comments as to what I'm doing. I identified the bug but I'm failing to find a solution for it.

Comment: Not a [mcve]...

Comment: Does your input contain characters other than braces?

Comment: @KaidulIslam  Hello, no, my input only contains the braces.

Comment: The edit is good, but not enough yet. The idea is that we should be able to copy & paste the code, compile it, and see the same you're seeing. *Getting* to a minimal example is, in itself, a basic debugging technique. Adding log output in strategic places to find out where the program flow is deviating from the expectation is also helpful. In other words, *what have you tried already* to find the bug?

Comment: Next, if your code would contain comments as to what you indended to do with a given construct, it would be easier to spot where your code doesn't work as intended. Without comments, we have to figure out *what* your code does, first, and *then* figure out if it makes sense this way, without any hint as to what you *intended*. (And the code giving unexpected results is *proof* that code and intention differ at some place. ;-) )

Comment: I added some explanations to the code as well as the structures and the explanation of what I have tried.

Comment: Yes, but anyone who wants to debug your code or check an answer for correctness will still have to write up the surrounding `main()` plus declarations. That's why I don't bother at this point.

Comment: I am *guessing* that your suspicions from the comments are correct -- that first `length = 0` should go before the loop (where you are hopefully also initializing `max` to zero). Have you tried?

Comment: Initially both length and max are set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved using stack. Here is my C++ implementation, hope you will feel no difficulty to understand the syntax and translate it into C.

```
int longestValidParentheses(string s) {
    stack <int> Stack;
    int maxLen = 0;
    int lastPos = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        if(s[i] == '(') {
            Stack.push(i);
        }
        else {
            if(Stack.empty()) {
                lastPos = i;
            }
            else {
                Stack.pop();
                if(Stack.empty()) {
                    maxLen = max(maxLen, i - lastPos);
                } else {
                    maxLen = max(maxLen, i - Stack.top());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return maxLen;
}
```

Sorry for the code rather than explanation as I am outside right now. I will put clarification if you need explanation on any part. For now, you can check with some input and pen-and-paper.

Comment: You seem to have dropped support for brackets and braces. I think the OP was using the term paranthesis [sic] loosely.

Comment: Yes, I had this solution already solved and just pasted from my archive. I think OP will be able to handle two other braces by modifying the code

Comment: Note that the question is tagged C, not C++.